# How to make "non-droppable group" in HTML / using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to create a "non-droppable group" in HTML / using CSS? For instance, if I have a simple element like this:

```
<div>
  Name: <input type="text"><span>Item</span>
</div>
```

Given enough size (width), it will be rendered like this:

[image]

But if the width becomes too small, the `Item` label and the `TextBox` will be "dropped" below the `Name` label like this:

[image]

Is it possible to create behavior such that when the width is small, the text box size will be adjusted but the labels will be retained in the left and right of the text box instead of being "dropped"?

Illustratively:

```
On large screen:
Name: |                       |Item

On small screen:
Name: |                 |Item
```

If this must be done using `Javascript`, I am ok with suggested answers using `Javascript` too.

Comment: have a look at media queries : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @NikhileshKV thanks for the suggestion, pal! Will take a look.

Comment: @NikhileshKV I tried using the answer using Media Queries, it helps but when the screen gets overly small, the behavior (of dropping the element below the previous element) is still retained. Any idea?

Comment: you can write another media query for your overly small screen and reduce the width and font size.

Comment: @NikhileshKV I see, it seems like the dropping behavior itself can't really be totally eliminated, is it? We can only do some workaround...

Comment: thats right. there isn't any such default behavior. You have to write media queries with custom behavior.

Comment: @NikhileshKV aih. :/ ok, thanks for the clarification.. it is helpful indeed - though not the way I want it to be...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use media queries:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-sm">
  Name: <input type="text"><span>Item</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input-sm input{
        width: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .input-sm input{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is good, but when the width becomes very small, the item is still dropped. Any idea?

Comment: @Ian Add another media query for min-width:480px and you will be good to go for very small size too.

Comment: @FaisalMohmand thanks for the comment. Seems like it is the only known way. :/ I thought there is a way for making a non-droppable group without workaround. But if that is the only way, then so be it... thanks again